# server side include not working for nested calls

Tags: apache, ssi, server-side-includes, shtml

I using server side includes to organize my files.

The nested files do not seem to work. For eg:-

**index.shtml** - this works fine

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <!--#include virtual="partials/head.shtml"-->
<body>
<!--#include virtual="partials/components/ads/horizontal-banner.shtml"-->
<div id="site-wrapper">
    <header id="site-header">
        <!--#include virtual="partials/header.shtml"-->
    </header>

    <div id="site-body">
        <!--#include virtual="partials/pages/home.shtml"-->
    </div>

    <footer id="site-footer">
        <!--#include virtual="partials/footer.shtml"-->
    </footer>
</div>
<!--#include virtual="partials/common.shtml"-->
```

inside **home.shtml**, there is another call

```
<!--#include virtual="../components/newsletter.shtml"-->
```

Following is the project structure :-

```
project
 - css
 - assets
 - js
 - partials
   - components
      - ads
        horizontal-banner.shtml
        vertical-banner.shtml
      newsletter.shtml
      help.shtml
   - pages
      home.shtml
      about.shtml
   header.shtml
   footer.shtml
   head.shtml
   common.shtml
index.shtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Apache's documentation - [Server Side Includes](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html):

> Using an include file for a header and/or a footer can reduce the
>   burden of these updates. You just have to make one footer file, and
>   then include it into each page with the include SSI command. The
>   include function can determine what file to include with either the
>   file attribute, or the virtual attribute. The file attribute is a file
>   path, relative to the current directory. That means that it cannot be
>   an absolute file path (starting with /), nor can it contain ../ as
>   part of that path. **The virtual attribute is probably more useful, and
>   should specify a URL relative to the document being served.** It can
>   start with a /, but must be on the same server as the file being
>   served.

Try to change the **home.shtml** like this:

```
<!--#include virtual="partials/components/newsletter.shtml"-->
```

.. and the **newsletter.shtml** file should be changed in the similar manner.

Comment: It worked when I placed the folder inside htdocs inside xampp. When I place it in a normal directory, it doesn't work. I don't know why....

Comment: Have you tried to look at the Apache's access and error log files? There should be an information about incorrect path if the location is the problem.